# drake ImportError: libmosek64.so.9.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, drake

After successful compiling `drake_cxx_python` I have got:
Output of `python3 -c 'import pydrake.all; print(pydrake.__file__)'`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/dmitriy/git/drake-build/install/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydrake/all.py", line 31, in <module>
    from .autodiffutils import *
ImportError: libmosek64.so.9.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I use this command sequence:

```
rm -rfv drake-build
git clone https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake.git
mkdir drake-build
cd drake-build
cmake -DWITH_GUROBI=ON -DWITH_MOSEK=ON ../drake
../drake/setup/ubuntu/source_distribution/install_prereqs_user_environment.sh 
make -j4
```

Next I specify `PATH` by adding it to `/.bashrc` file:

```
#drake
cd ~/git/drake-build/
export PYTHONPATH=${PWD}/install/lib/python3.8/site-packages:${PYTHONPATH}
cd
```

The output of `sudo python3 -c 'import pydrake.all; print(pydrake.__file__)'`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydrake'
```

I installed Mosek use that: [instructions](https://docs.mosek.com/9.3/install/installation.html)

Output of `ldd install/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydrake/solvers/__init__.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so | grep -i mosek`:

```
    libmosek64.so.9.3 => not found
    libmosek64.so.9.2 => not found
```

Output of `readelf -d install/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydrake/solvers/__init__.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so | grep -i path`:

```
 0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/]
```

And at the same time, there is a file `libmosek64.so.9.3*`:

```
~/git/drake-build/install/lib$ l -a
./
../
cmake/
libcilkrts.so.5*
libddApp.so*
libdrake_ibex.so*
libdrake_lcm.so*
libdrake_marker.so*
libdrake.so*
libgurobi95.so@
libgurobi.so.9.5.1*
libmosek64.so.9.3*
```

Why it doesn't see it?

I tried install drake using pip and I have got  the same error:
output of `python3 -c 'import pydrake.all; print(pydrake.__file__)'`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/dmitriy/git/drake-build/install/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydrake/all.py", line 31, in <module>
    from .autodiffutils import *
ImportError: libmosek64.so.9.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Aside: There is no need to run those [instructions](https://docs.mosek.com/9.3/install/installation.html) you linked.  Drake downloads it's copy of Mosek internally, automatically.

Comment: Please share the exact steps to reproduce the problem.  You say you did "compiling drake_cxx_python" -- what commands exactly did you run, and what CMake configuration settings did you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://drake.mit.edu/from_source.html#building-the-python-bindings for instructions.

Pasting it into here:

---

To use the Python bindings from Drake externally, we recommend using CMake.
As an example:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake.git
mkdir drake-build
cd drake-build
cmake ../drake
make -j
```

Please note the additional CMake options which affect the Python bindings:

- `-DWITH_GUROBI={ON, [OFF]}` - Build with Gurobi enabled.
- `-DWITH_MOSEK={ON, [OFF]}` - Build with MOSEK™ enabled.
- `-DWITH_SNOPT={ON, [OFF]}` - Build with SNOPT enabled.

`{...}` means a list of options, and the option surrounded by `[...]` is
the default option. An example of building `pydrake` with both Gurobi and
MOSEK™, without building tests:

```bash
cmake -DWITH_GUROBI=ON -DWITH_MOSEK=ON ../drake
```

You will also need to have your `PYTHONPATH` configured correctly.

*Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal):*

```bash
cd drake-build
export PYTHONPATH=${PWD}/install/lib/python3.8/site-packages:${PYTHONPATH}
```

*macOS:*

```bash
cd drake-build
export PYTHONPATH=${PWD}/install/lib/python3.9/site-packages:${PYTHONPATH}
```

---

In particular, in the steps you quoted above, there was no mention of `PYTHONPATH`.  Setting a correct `PYTHONPATH` is required to use Drake correctly.

---

Using Drake git sha `e4330af2c97a14170f873b25eb42fa0449feac9d`:

When I run these commands:

```
mkdir 73219153
cd 73219153
git clone https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake.git
mkdir drake-build
cd drake-build
cmake -DWITH_GUROBI=OFF -DWITH_MOSEK=ON ../drake
../drake/setup/ubuntu/source_distribution/install_prereqs_user_environment.sh 
make -j30
export PYTHONPATH=${PWD}/install/lib/python3.8/site-packages:${PYTHONPATH}
python3 -c 'import pydrake.all; print(pydrake.__file__)'
```

... then it works for me.  Here's what I see for library paths:

```
jwnimmer@call-cps:~/tmp/73219153/drake-build$ readelf -d install/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydrake/solvers/__init__.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so | grep -i path
 0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [$ORIGIN/../../../..:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/]
jwnimmer@call-cps:~/tmp/73219153/drake-build$ ldd install/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydrake/solvers/__init__.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so | grep -i mosek
    libmosek64.so.9.3 => /home/jwnimmer/tmp/73219153/drake-build/install/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydrake/solvers/../../../../libmosek64.so.9.3 (0x00007fbd03626000)
```

I don't know why your library paths aren't working.  You'll need to provide better reproduction instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are seeing two versions of MOSEK required.  Are you repeatedly installing Drake into the same `install` folder over and over?  That's not how CMake works.  With CMake, you need to `rm -rf` the install folder prior to re-running any install.  Otherwise, it never cleans up any old files, and they could be corrupting the install.  In particular, this is probably https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/14224.

Comment: Thanks, of course I remove it before new installation using `rm`.